# Negate Angular ngIf "as"

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there an option to negate "as" syntax within structural directives?

I've tried to write something like this `<div *loader="!(data$ | async as data)"></div>` but this gets immediately stressed by the IDE that this is incorrect syntax.

Is there any way to negate this syntax?

The main idea is that I have an observable where I get the data. If the data is absent I need to show the loader. (`*loader="true"` shows the loader) and therefore I'm trying to negate the expression.

I know that I could create some extra variable in order to store loading state or the data but I would like to stay with what I have.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) with an **else** block with a template:

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else loading">
    ...
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading User Data...</ng-template>
```

You can see a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjyqzn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

the result of expression is always saved into `as var` variable, but you won't be able to have data and negate it in one structural directive. you can do `*loader="!(data$ | async) as data"` but you will get this `false` in your data when it comes. I think you sould rework your `loader` directive to vise versa logic, so falsy value would show loader instead, and truthy one would be passed to a template.